# Кодировка для веб-сайта

Tags: apache, nginx, apache2, charset

Есть очень старый сервер. На нем несколько веб сайтов с разными доменами и поддоменами.

Один из сайтов полностью построен на кодировке windows-1251, браузер отдает utf-8, на выходе получаем крякозябры.
Я пробовал:

1. Изменить default_charset в php.ini - в общем-то помогло, только слетели все остальные сайты где кодировка utf-8
2. В nginx менял charset и source_charset. Ноль на масу.
3. Сделал с нжинкса переадресацию на апач и в .htaccess прописал php_value default_charset.
   В общем, чтобы я не пробовал, в заголовке все равно получается "charset utf-8".
   Перевести вручную файлы не получиться, их там очень много

Comment: Перевести не вручную, очевидно! Скрипт с iconv можно написать за пару минут и ещё быстрее нагуглить готовый https://gist.github.com/akost/2304819

Comment: Спасибо! Вы мне очень помогли!